# Youtube api v3 error "SSL is required to perform this operation"

Tags: wordpress, youtube-javascript-api

Looking for some insight into how to get video information using youtube's v3 api.

When passing the url, the json response I get is:

```
{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"sslRequired","message":"SSL is required to perform this operation."}],"code":403,"message":"SSL is required to perform this operation."}}
```

All I'm trying to do is get basic information (title, description, etc) so I used "snippet" for the part.

Here's a sample url i'm using:

```
http://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=Ho4XgLj40Ss&part=snippet
```

I have tried creating an API Key and adding `&key={my_api_key}` to the end of that url.

If the environment matters, I'm using a jquery getJSON request in a custom Wordpress theme.

I should mention that in the "try it now" section in the documentation, it returns a nice json object - with the OAuth off.

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand?

Comment: I guess I'm not sure why I'm getting the error at all. Why does getting public information for a public video require ssl? How do I go about making the proper request.

Comment: I could have swore I tried that... *headdesk* Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same problem for another API.
As SLaks pointed out in the comments, just use `https://` instead of `http://`

In your case, try :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=Ho4XgLj40Ss&part=snippet
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Xavier's answer, if you are using this API in a `Flutter environment`, then you can change your

```
Uri.http(baseUrl, endPointUrl, parameters);
```

to

```
Uri.https(baseUrl, endPointUrl, parameters);
```

Notice the `https` above.